# Activity's onCreate handler is called two times

Tags: android

I am working on adding [Interstitial Ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) to an Android game application. The Ad is created in the activity's onCreate handler and displayed when the game is reset, loaded, etc...

The Ad works stable on my 32-bit phone and on emulators, but there is a specific scenario on my 64-bit phone where I get the following strange effect: if I deactivate the app when the Ad is open and then click on the app icon the activity's `onCreate` handler is called as if the app is not started yet (and the app stops working), but if I activate the app back by listing the apps and clicking on the app snapshot it activates normally via `onRestart` and works fine. This happens only if I run the app first time after a clean install from the store (not via USB).

I wonder if anyone can comment this. See [logs and source code](https://developernote.com/2019/09/adding-interstitial-ads-to-a-qt-application-on-android-platform/) on my blog.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that illustrates the behavior you are asking about.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice probably the minimal example (or at least the starting point for further investigation) is this https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/admob/InterstitialExample but I it is not clear enough how to test it, because my strange effect happens only if 1) the app is installed from the Store (not with USB), 2) started the first time 3) on 64-bit phone. Theoretically I can create an app in my Store account and upload it. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I was unable to reproduce the bug with this example.

Comment: Any response? I have similar problem with two times call onCreate()

Comment: @Čamo I changed launchMode in the application manifest from singleTop to singleTask and the main activity’s onCreate handler stopped being called when I reactivate the app by clicking on its icon, see |https://developernote.com/2019/09/adding-interstitial-ads-to-a-qt-application-on-android-platform/ for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing `launchMode` in the application manifest from `singleTop` to `singleTask` and the main activity’s `onCreate` handler stopped being called when I reactivate the app by clicking on its icon, but I am not sure it is an ideal solution, see [this blog post for details](https://developernote.com/2019/09/adding-interstitial-ads-to-a-qt-application-on-android-platform/).